# RD Session Host Configuration doesn't list my SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, rdp, windows, certificate

I'm trying to change SSL certificate from auto-generated to another one, e.g. custom self-signed made by makecert.

But

```
RD Session Host Configuration snap-in -> Connections -> RDP-Tcp -> General -> Select
```

doesn't list it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not *.cer* but **.pfx** file should be imported under `certmgr.mmc -> Local Computer -> Personal` store